# WKWebView RunJavaScriptConfirmPanel Unable to locate the block to delegate conversion method

Tags: javascript, xamarin.ios, ios11, wkwebview

Im trying to capture confirm panels in Xamarin.iOS App but it only works in simulator.

```
[Foundation.Export("webView:runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:completionHandler:")]
public void RunJavaScriptConfirmPanel(WKWebView webView, string message, WKFrameInfo frame, Action<bool> completionHandler)
{

    var alertController = UIAlertController.Create(null, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);

    alertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Sí", UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, okAction =>
    {
        completionHandler(true);
    }));
    alertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("No", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, cancelAction =>
    {
        completionHandler(false);
    }));

    _controller.PresentViewController(alertController, true, null);

}
```

I'm following the next example from xamarin official page ( https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/web_view/handle_javascript_alerts/ ) but when I run the app on my iPhone 8 plus I'm getting this error:

ObjCRuntime.RuntimeException:
Unable to locate the block to delegate conversion method for the method XXXX.iOS.Infrastructure.JSDelegate.RunJavaScriptConfirmPanel's parameter #4. Please file a bug at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com.

This is what I'm using:

Environment

ios 11.3
Xcode 9.3
Xamarin.iOS : Version: 11.9.1.24 (Visual Studio Community)
Visual Studio Mac 7.4.2 (build 12)

Any Ideas ?? I don't understand why only works in simulator the official example ...

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin's example only was worked in simulator but I changed the method signature to :

public override void RunJavaScriptConfirmPanel(WKWebView webView, string message, WKFrameInfo frame, Action completionHandler)
{

Without any Foundation Export and now is working in simulator and phisical device.